# zeros of a simple polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

For $x, y \in GF[2^n]$, consider the two-parameter polynomial $P(x,y) = x \cdot y + f(x) + g(y)$, where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary polynomials on $GF[2^n]$.

Can we say anything about the number of zeros of $P$? Intuitively one would expect that the product $x \cdot y$ does not coincide with the sum of two one-parameter polynomials $f$ and $g$ at many points, but is there a (simple) way to show this?

Comment: [A related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/844544/11619). A duplicate at a glance, actually (but unanswered).

Comment: Indeed, the other question did not attract any answers, so I thought I would distill it to its core - which appears to be difficult enough!

Comment: This is a fun problem. Just started thinking. Unless I made a mistake I can get 9/16 correct on $GF(4)$, and also prove that it is the best possible. I will answer, if I make some real progress. The constraint (expressed as a probability in the other question) may be the key, but I don't really understand what's going on here.

Comment: @Jyrk: Yes, it is a fun problem indeed. We can also show this bound for $GF(4)$ but it is hard to see any pattern for $n > 2$. This appears to be a much harder problem then originally thought, so probably not suitable for stack exchange. If you have any ideas, feel free to contact me directly at marcotom.ch@gmail.com.